# Using the vscode-regex plugin?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I've installed the [vscode-regex](https://github.com/chrmarti/vscode-regex) plugin and I'm now attempting to get it to work.  I have the following javascript and text document side by side in VSCode:

[image]

However I'm not getting any matches in the `email.txt` document.  I tried the keyboard commant ctrl + alt + m, but still no love.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why the "off-topic" vote to close? Is not "software tools commonly used by programmers" specifically on-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instructions of the VS-Code [Regex Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrmarti.regex) Plugin look straightforward: Just open the test and the sample in side-by-side view, hit the hotkey `Ctrl+Alt+M` (`⌥⌘M`).

Unfortunately, I run into the same and could not get it working initially.
**The solution**: I've used the hotkey, then **click the grey link**: *Test Regex...*

[image]

Actually, the link and the hotkey do the same. However, the hotkey only works after the matching has been triggered by the link or clicking the actual regex pattern (as mentioned by [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark)) first.

Comment: It also seems clicking anywhere in the actual regex expression also triggers the extension to work.

Comment: Awesome - I got it - Thanks!  I installed it and then installed an update to VSCode and I think the update may have nuked the original install, as I had to reinstall it.